# IE11 twitching problem with button, vertical flex and absolute positioned element

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

**Update:**

I've added a screen record to show the problem. This is reproduced in browserStack ie11, with the "run code snippet" button in this question.
[image]

---

I'm working on a dropdown menu, which needs to work in IE11. However the flex container twitches when the menu opens up. Not using flex on the container or not using the button tag would solve the problem, however the container is outta my control and I'd prefer to use button if it is possible. Does anybody know what is wrong with this?

```js
var handle = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var inner = document.getElementsByClassName('inner')[0];

var dropdownOpen = false;

handle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen;

  inner.style.height = dropdownOpen ? '80px' : '0';
});
```

```css
.outter {
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
}

.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class='outter'>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div class='main'>
    <button>handle</button>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='inner' style='height: 0'>
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't see the twitching in IE11.

Comment: I have tested your code on my side, [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izJTg.png) seems similar when using Chrome, Microsoft Edge and IE browser, you could check it. Is there any other script or code? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).